# Mailgun invalid parameters

Tags: php, api, mailgun

Why this code is giving the error while sending email to mailgun mailing list ?

```
$mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN,[

'from'          => 'test@samples.mailgun.org',
'to'            => MAILGUN_LIST,
'subject'       => $subject,
'html'          => $body.'<br><br><a href="%unsubscribe_url%">Unsubscribe</a>'

                    ]);
```

The fatal error i am getting is give below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters: The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in domain settings. in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php:226 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(99): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(151): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->send('POST', 'sandboxb676bd53...', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream), Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(118): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('sandboxb676bd53...', Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(61): Mailgun\Mailgun->post('sandbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php on line 226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Uncaught Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters: The
>   parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox
>   subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or
>   add the address to authorized recipients in domain settings

If you are sending from the sandbox domain then you need to configure the allowed recipient list (max 5 users). See [here](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258) for more details.

I'm also not sure it allows your to send to a mailing list either under the sandbox. Also, your from address should also have the same domain as the sandbox domain.

Comment: I have added the mail id which is in subscribed list to authorized recipients list but still throws the same error and I think we don't need to use the same domain in "from" address.

Comment: whenever I've attempted to send an email from the sandbox with a different domain it has failed silently. also are the recipients in the list also set as authorised recipients? I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun Email

```
                    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
                    'from'    => ''.$txt_fname.' <'.$txt_femail.'>',
                    'to'      => ''.$email_address.'',
                    'subject' => ''.$txt_subject.'',
                    'text' =>''.$txt_only.'',
                    'html'    => '<html><body>'.$email_message.'</body></html>'
                ),$file_array);
```