# MailGun parameters are invalid for no apparent reason

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-2.3, mailgun

I have a very simple code that uses MailGun in my Symfony2 application:

```
public function sendNewEmail()
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Any random subject')
                    ->setFrom('welcome@mycompany.com')
                    ->setTo('myemail@email.com')
                    ->setBody('Mybody');
    $this->mailer->send($message);

    return null;
}
```

This code use to work very fine, but after some days ago it simply doesn't work anymore. It returns the error in the end.

I have no idea of what this problem can be once I haven't changed almost anything in code.

How could I discover what is?

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters: "The
>   parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Sandbox
>   subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or
>   add the address to authorized recipients in domain settings." at
>   /srv/www/MyCodeSource/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php
>   line 169 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters(code: 0):
>   The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!
>   Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own
>   domain or add the address to authorized recipients in domain settings.
>   at
>   /srv/www/MyCodeSource/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php:169)"}
>   []

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140281/mailgun-invalid-parameters take a look at this.

Comment: I checked this answer but is not my case, I've been using for many months my code as it is. Now it has stopped working

Comment: As I edited my answer, they made a update in their system that made mandatory the custom domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it looks like it was the sandbox domain that I was using that was causing the problem.

I added a custom domain and added the entries in my DNS, etc... and now it's working

But the weirdest is that I was using it for months and I've never had this problem. When, maybe it was an exception that was eventually fixed by MailGun.

---

**Update**
Just to confirm what I said above: I received an email of MailGun

> We've implemented changes that were announced and several
>   notifications were sent out informing customers starting from November
>   1st. On December 1st, 2016...All domains, regardless of the creation
>   date, will be required to verify the domain to continue sending and
>   receiving messages.

That is why my email stopped suddenly. And after they explained that I should change the domain, set the DNS configuration, etc...

And well, they sent the instructions after I've done them, but they had a nice, fast and clear support. Just giving the credit...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official notification of this change: http://blog.mailgun.com/domain-verification-changes-for-new-and-existing-domains/